# Photoshop fit layer to image width or height

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize

After Effects has these menus where you can transform a layer to fit to composition width or composition height, but I can't find this menu in Photoshop, every time I place "embedded" a file or drag and drop a file on my image loaded in Photoshop, it shrinks it down and puts it on the image, although both images are the same size.

The only workaround I currently know is to load the image separately, select all (Ctrl + A) and copy and paste it on the image but this only works if both images are the same size. If they're not, I'd have to find out the size of first image, resize the second image to be the same width or same height of the first image and then copy paste it, which is a hassle.

I searched a lot on Google and couldn't find any solution, what I found was "fit image to canvas" which I don't need.

Comment: If I understood correctly, I believe I have a script for just that: https://github.com/joonaspaakko/paste-or-place-inside-selection-photoshop-script though it only handles pasting and placing and not resizing after the fact — Gifs (dialog is outdated in both): [selection method](https://github.com/joonaspaakko/paste-or-place-inside-selection-photoshop-script/blob/master/readme-images/selection-method.gif?raw=true), [active layer method](https://github.com/joonaspaakko/paste-or-place-inside-selection-photoshop-script/blob/master/readme-images/active-layer-method.gif?raw=true).

Comment: Sounds like you might be looking for *Edit > Preferences > General > Skip transform when placing*.